# Контролирование плеера SWF от VideoJS

Tags: javascript, flashvideo

При использовании videojs как swf плеера и обращении к swf через апи не получается ничего изменить.
Код создания плеера:

```
var content = document.createElement("video");
content.setAttribute('id', 'player1');
content.setAttribute('width', '100%');
content.setAttribute('height', '100%');
content.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
document.getElementById('player').appendChild(content);
videojs(content,{techOrder: ["flash"],
    src: theater.isHDEnabled() ? mplowhd : mphighhd,
    autoplay: true,
    preload: true,
    poster: req.image_medium,
    loop: true
    }).ready = this.onReady;
```

Альтернативный способ, который также не даёт этого же доступа (swfobject):

```
var flashvars = {
    src: theater.isHDEnabled() ? mplowhd : mphighhd,
    autoplay: true,
    preload: true,
    poster: req.image_medium,
};

var params = {
    allowScriptAccess: "always",
    wmode: 'opaque',
    bgcolor: '#000000',
    "data-setup": '{"techOrder": ["flash"]}'
};

var attributes = {
    id: "player",
    name: "player",
    class: "vjs-tech",
};
swfobject.embedSWF("video-js.swf", "player", "100%", "100%", "10.3", "", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

функция onReady в данном случае срабатывает сама при прогрузке swfobject'a:

```
this.onReady = function(e) {
this.player = videojs(e, {techOrder: ['flash'],})
console.log(this.player);};
```

Далее при проигрывании видео и попытке вызвать апи он не реагирует вообще, такое чувство, что не связан с плеером. Хочу сделать такой функционал, чтобы работала перемотка видео, регулирование громкости плеера, смены видео.(Именно swf, html5 не поддерживается, и это не исправить.)